# Working git from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, git

So I use Github for Windows (that fancy GUI app) to manage my various git-based projects, but I've noticed that on my machine I can't use the command line git to do anything with my projects. From the windows command line I'm unable to pull or push anything (I get 'permission denied: publickey' errors), nor can I ssh into github from git bash, but from the app everything works just fine.

I've checked my github account and made sure the ssh keys (both named github_rsa, one has .pub on it) from my .ssh folder are there, and I was under the impression that both command line and GUI git used the same set of keys? What could be the problem here?

Comment: Do you use standard windows command.com or Bash Shell ?

Comment: I've tried both, neither works.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kristol/archive/2013/07/02/the-git-command-line-101-for-windows-users.aspx

Comment: Try this steps: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey